# Optimize Oracle order by query

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, query-optimization, partitioning

I have a table with around 5 million rows that look like this:

**Erp_in:**

```
corr_id varchar(50) (almost Unique)
corr_type nvarchar(1) (4 distinct values)
interface varchar(20) (around 10 distinct values)
indate DateTime
```

With 3 different index on (corr_id, interface and indate)
And also I have another table which I usally left join with the original table, with about 100000 rows

**Erp_In_failed:**

```
corr_id
interface
error (clob)   
input (clob)
```

with index on (corr_id and interface)

The query I want to optimize is Simple as this:

```
SELECT a.corr_id, a.interface, a.indate, b.error 
FROM erp_in a left join erp_in_failed b on a.corr_id = b.corr_id and a.interface =          b.interface
Order by a.indate desc;
```

If I remove the order by, the query isn't taking that long, but ordering the data takes around 3 minutes if not more.

What can I do to optimize the query?
I was thinking on Partitioning / Removing old data to history table / maybe creating a sequence primary key and order by it or anything else you have in mind...

**Edit:**
Execution plan says full table scan, and it's not the join that takes so long it's the order by.
Even this query takes forever:

```
SELECT * FROM erp_in
ORDER BY indate;
```

I have tried using Paging, but that doesn't work also, and takes few minutes for 20 results, maybe I am doing it wrong?

If I add WHERE clause on indate field, it uses the index, but only when it is less than 20 days old, anything other than that still uses full table scan. (even with 40 days, adding INDEX hint made the query run faster, but still not enough).

And just for the curiosity, I have a simple table with 1 million rows, and order by takes few seconds, what's the difference? is 1 million is enough to sort it in RAM?

Thanks,

Comment: First of all you should put execution plan of this query in your question. Try create combined indexes: (corr_id,interface, indate), (interface, corr_id, indate) or something similar on both tables and provide execution plan after that.

Comment: When you say the query isn't taking that long without the orderby, are you sure you measure the time to return all results and not only to return the first results?

Comment: What is the purpose of this query?  What consumes the result set?

Comment: Web site report... As i said even with pagination It didn't seem faster.

Comment: You're selecting all the data, which means Oracle will do a full table scan, which means it will sort afterwards, which means you wait till everythings done. A first_rows hint would get you results faster using the index, but increase total execution time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sorting five million rows including about one hundred thousand clobs.  It is unlikely you'll be able to do that in memory; if you run the query in SQL*Plus with stats on you should see the query writing out to disk a lot.

One way of improving the performance will be to add more GB to your buffer cache, but that may be an expensive option and not a quick one either.

Building a composite index on `erp_in(indate desc, corr_id, interface)` could help as well, because the results from the driving table will be pre-sorted and so the ordering should take less work.  Partitioning by INDATE might have a similar effect, but partitioning is a chargeable extra to the Enterprise Edition and hence is not a cheap fix (gobs more memory will probably be a lot cheaper).

Your reference to archiving old data suggests that you don't actually want to retrieve all the records.  If this is the case then reducing the size of the result set with a WHERE clause would help a lot.  The easiest way to tune something is not to do work in the first place.

Adding a primary key and ordering by it won't reduce the amount of effort required to to the actual sort.

---

> "so should I partition by date? will it help without adding WHERE
>   clause on INDATE field"

It depends.  Partitioning introduces some physical organization of the table, so the rows will (at least) require less sorting.  How much less depends on the granularity of the partition: partition by a range on one day and the table is pretty much already in INDATE order, partition by a range of one year and it's much less so.

However, bear in mind that partitioning is not primarily a performance option.  It is an option for managing data, especially loading, and availability. In fact, it may downgrade the performance of some queries, queries which don't suit the ordering applied by the partition key.

So, should you partition by date?  Not a question we can answer.  Answering it requires the sort of in-depth knowledge of your system which you have and we lack.  But if you have the licenses it is certainly an option you should investigate and benchmark.

Comment: I already have enterprise edition so the price is not issue here, so should I partition by date? will it help without adding WHERE clause on INDATE field?

Comment: EE is not enough: "partitioning is a *chargeable extra* "

Comment: I know we already have partition on another table, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @APC are you available for paid consulting?

Comment: @Toolkit - I'm a freelancer, so in principle yes.

Comment: @APC can you please drop me an email at proxy82028@yandex.com

Answer (score 1):

Are you really fetching so many rows to web server? If yes, review your code to narrow down to what's required.

1. Try archiving old data to another table based on datetime. Re-write logic to fetch older data only when required.
2. As others have mentioned, indexes / keys should help a mile in most cases

If you can't do any of the above, another ugly solution (not sure if it will not go worse) is to create in-memory table, filter and fetch what's required and then fetch CLOB data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you experimented with additional indexes? I have done something similar and I have used a clustered index on the `indate DateTime` field. This is on a premise that most queries will be bounded to some time period and that rebalancing of B-trees will not be an issue as most inserts will with increasing key values. Get the execution plan for your query and look if you could not optimize it a bit.

Comment: I have tried reading, But I can't find the disadvantages of clustered index, How can I know for sure if I should use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a composite index `(indate desc, corr_id, interface)` on erp_in will use the index and the query will be faster.

But you should better find a way to minimize the size of data to be sorted.

For example get only the last two days:

```
SELECT a.corr_id, a.interface, a.indate, b.error 
FROM erp_in a left join erp_in_failed b 
     on a.corr_id = b.corr_id and a.interface = b.interface
WHERE indate > trunc(sysdate - 1)
Order by a.indate desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my experience, I was stuck with similar issue as metnioned by question author.

My query was long, it includes several tables and joins, Here I am just trying to showcase my scenario with simple query.It is returning around 80,0000 records. I found that order by is the bottleneck part in my query.

```
select column1, colum2 from table order by colum2
```

It was happening like my query was using index on column1 when I checked the execution plan.

I just included column1 in order by.

```
select column1, column2 from table order by column2, column1
```

It has helped me, sample reading was like before change it was taking 8 seconds, after above change it is taking only 2 seconds.

I find the [link](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by) very helpful for this.